# Find departments with no employees

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

We were given an assignment in class to provide at the minimum two different solutions to find departments, which don't have any employees. As you can see from below I completed the task successfully.

An additional solution is extra credit, which I like to get. Unfortunately, I can't think of a third solution and was hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Would something with a MINUS function work?

Below is my setup and 2 working test cases. Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE departments
(
    department_id, 
    department_name
) AS
SELECT 1, 'IT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Sales' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'DBA' FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE employees 
(
    employee_id, 
    first_name, last_name, 
    hire_date, 
    salary,  
    department_id
) AS
SELECT 1, 'Lisa', 'Saladino', DATE '2001-04-03', 100000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Abby', 'Abbott', DATE '2001-04-04', 50000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Beth', 'Cooper', DATE '2001-04-05', 60000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Carol', 'Orr', DATE '2001-04-06', 70000,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Vicky', 'Palazzo', DATE '2001-04-07', 88000,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Cheryl', 'Ford', DATE '2001-04-08', 110000,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Leslee', 'Altman', DATE '2001-04-10', 66666, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Jill', 'Coralnick', DATE '2001-04-11', 190000, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Faith', 'Aaron', DATE '2001-04-17', 122000,2 FROM DUAL;

/* departments with no employees */

select 
    d.department_id,
    d.department_name
from 
    employees e 
right join 
    departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by 
    d.department_id, d.department_name
having 
    count(e.employee_id) = 0;
```

Output:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    DEPARTMENT_NAME
--------------------------------
      3          Sales
```

```
SELECT 
    d.department_id,
    d.department_name 
FROM 
    departments d
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM employees e 
                WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id)
```

Output:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    DEPARTMENT_NAME
--------------------------------
      3          Sales
```

Comment: Yes, MINUS may work: set of department_id from departments MINUS set of department_id from departments joined to employees

Comment: It is possible to use `minus`, but it is a set operation and requires two subqueries to have the same number and type of columns. As long as you have no `department_name` in `employees` table it will require the second access to the `departments` table resulting in performance loss. You may also use `departments left join employees ... where employees.department_id is null` but it is effectively the same as `not exists` (has the same query plan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use left join as the following:

```
select 
     d.department_id,
     d.department_name
from departments d left join employees e 
on e.department_id=d.department_id
where e.employee_id is null
```

Also, you may use a sub query as the following:

```
select department_id, department_name
from departments
where department_id not in (select department_id from employees)
```

And with `minus` you may try:

```
select department_id, department_name
from departments
minus
select 
     d.department_id,
     d.department_name
from departments d join employees e 
on e.department_id=d.department_id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/q4_FXUnk).

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query-

```
SELECT * 
  FROM departments
 WHERE department_id in (SELECT department_id
                           FROM departments
                          minus 
                         SELECT DISTINCT department_id
                           FROM employees
                        );
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/HjOAcDRN)

Comment: Note: there's no need to use `distinct` because `minus` does not consider different instatces of the same tuple as different tuples.